# Button Click Event Within Another

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have two buttons Start button and Stop button .I run my program by clicking on start button. I want to stop the program during the start button . But the program will not responde until the start buttun finish its job. How i can do check the stop buttun during the start. i heard about threading but i do not know how i can do it.

```
Private Sub Button_Start (ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  //my code
  //check always if the user push stop if no continue if yes go to this sub
  //my code
end sub

Private Sub Button_Stop  (ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
  stopClick = True
  Dim Response As Integer
  Response = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to exit?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
  If Response = vbYes Then
    Me.Close()
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need four spaces to indent your code blocks at this site.  Try naming your controls.  Is Button1 start?  Is Button3 stop?

Comment: yes Button1 is start and Button3 is  stop

Comment: @user3556795 With all due respect: Why do you declare `Response` as an [Integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bkb8w2.aspx), assign it a [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) and compare it to a [MsgBoxResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.msgboxresult(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use threading  put button1 code in a function and use the thread .

you can refer to this example

```
'Thread created to handle the Background process for start_function
Dim t As System.Threading.Thread

Private Sub start_function()
    While True
        'your code here for Eg:
        Dim i As Integer
        i = i + 1
    End While

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    t = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Me.start_function)
    t.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    t.Abort()
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually i am new in this field i could not know how i can use it :(

Comment: sorry I got this error how i can fix it Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Chart1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Answer (score 0):

Drag a backgroundworker component onto your form.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    Me.Text = "Busy Doing Work"

    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub btnStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click
    Me.Text = "Asking to Cancel"
    BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    While Not BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End While
End Sub


Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Me.Text = "Cancelled"
End Sub

End Class
```